# How properly use each function in this example?

Tags: jquery, function, each

Working on this code and am quite stuck.. What I'm trying to achieve is that when there are more then 2 selections in the selection div, the overlay message's bottom position moves from 10px (defined in CSS) to 90px (defined in the jQuery). The problem is it's applying on all overlay messages (90px), even though when I log the results I get 2,3 and 4 as separate results. Why isn't it applying the results separately to each wrapper div? Isn't this what the each function does, to apply on each separate?

Thanks!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6qD52/

Code:

```
$(".overlay").each(function() {
    selection_number = $(this).parent().find(".selections").find(".selection").length;
    console.log(selection_number);

     if ((selection_number) > 2) {
        $(".overlay_message").css({bottom: 90});
     }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('.overlay_message')` selects *all* of the overlay messages. You want the one inside of your element:

```
$(this).find(".overlay_message").css({bottom: 90});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and solution Blender, works as it should indeed!

Answer (score 3):

You want to select the `.overlay_message` that is *inside the element you're operating on*:

```
$(this).find('.overlay_message')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Selects the 'overlay_message' div inside the current 'overlay' div
$(this).find(".overlay_message").css({bottom: 90});
```

Instead of this:

```
// Selects all the 'overlay_message' div
$(".overlay_message").css({bottom: 90});
```